# Why are gen1/gen2 collections slower than gen0?

Tags: c#, garbage-collection

From my anecdotal knowledge, short-lived object creation isn't too troublesome in terms of GC - implying, gen0 collections are extremely fast. Gen1/gen2 collections, however, appear to be a little more "dreaded", i.e. said to usually be a whole lot slower than gen0.

Why is that? What makes, say, a gen2 collection on average significantly slower than gen0?

I'm not aware of any structural differences between the collection approaches itself (i.e., things done in the mark/sweep/compaction phase), am I missing something? Or is it just that e.g. gen2 tends to be larger than gen0, hence more objects to check?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of reasons which come to mind:

1. They're bigger. Collecting gen1 means also collecting gen0, and doing a gen2 collection means collecting all three. The lower generations are sized smaller as well, as gen0 is collected most frequently and so needs to be cheap.
2. The main cost of a collection is a function of the number of objects which survive, not the number which die. Generational garbage collectors are built around the generational hypothesis, which says that objects tend to live for a short time, or a long time, but not often in the middle. Gen0 collections by their very definition are comprised mainly of objects which die in that generation, and so collections are cheap: gen1 and gen2 collections have a higher proportion of objects which survive (gen2 should ideally be comprised *only* of objects which survive), and so are more expensive.
3. If an object is in gen0, then it can only be referenced by other gen0 objects, or by objects in higher generations which were updated to refer to it. Therefore to see whether an object in gen0 is referenced, the GC needs to check other gen0 objects, as well as only those objects in higher generations which have been updated to point to lower-generation objects (which the GC tracks, see "card tables"). To see whether a gen1 object is referenced it needs to check all of gen0 and gen1, and updated objects in gen2.

Answer (score 2):

To amplify on canton7's answer, it's worthwhile to note a couple of additional things, one of which increases the cost of all collections (but especially gen1 and gen2) but reduces the cost of allocations between them, and one of which reduces the cost of gen0 and gen1 collections:

1. Many garbage collectors behave in a fashion somewhat analogous to cleaning out a building by moving everything of value to another building, dynamiting the original, and rebuilding the empty shell.  A gen0 collection, which moves things from the gen0 building to the gen1 building, will be fairly fast because the gen0 "building" won't have much stuff in it.  A gen2 collection would have to move everything that was in the much larger gen2 building.  Garbage collection systems may use a separate building for smaller gen2 objects and larger ones, and manage the larger buildings by tracking individual regions of free space, but moving smaller objects and reclaiming storage wholesale is less work than trying to manage all the individual regions of storage that would become eligible for reuse.  A key point to observe about generations here, however, is that even when it's necessary to scan a gen1 or gen2 object, it won't be necessary to move it since the "building" it's in isn't targeted for immediate demolition.
2. Many systems use a "card table" which can record whether each 4K chunk of memory has been written, or contains a reference that was used to modify an object, since the last gen0 or gen1 collection.  This significantly slows down the first write to any such region of storage, but during a gen0 and gen1 collections, it makes it possible to skip the examination of a lot of objects.  The details of how the card table are used vary, but the basic concept is that if code has a large array of references, but most of it falls within 4K blocks that aren't tagged, the GC can know without even looking in those blocks that any newer objects which would be accessible through them will *also* be accessible in other ways, and thus it will be possible to find all gen0 objects without bothering to look in those blocks at all.

Note that even simplistic garbage-collection systems without card tables can be simply and easily made to benefit from the principle of generational GC.  For example, on Commodore 64 BASIC, whose garbage collector is horrendously slow, a program that has created lots of long-lived strings can avoid lengthy garbage-collection cycles by using a couple peek and poke statements to adjust the top-of-string-heap pointer just below the bottom of the long-lived strings so they won't be considered for relocation/reclamation.  If a program uses hundreds of strings that will last throughout program execution (e.g. a table of two-digit hex strings from 00 to FF), and just a handful of other strings, this may slash garbage-collection times by more than an order of magnitude.